# How do I choose servers to minimize latency to a critical third-party service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, latency

I would like to spin up a cloud server that has the minimum possible ping to a third-party service. Do you just get on AWS and keep making servers in new Availability Zones until the ping is good enough? Are there easier ways to do this? Am I likely to find a better ping by trying a lot of different cloud providers?

Comment: Where _is_ the third party service?

Comment: I am not able to rightly apprehend the confusion of ideas that leads you to believe this is a *good* solution. What happens when the Availability Zone you created your stuff in goes down? Do you just re-do the ping-testing in all the remaining zones and pick a new winner? Seems like an inefficient use of time while your app is down...

Answer (score 4):

> Are there easier ways to do this?

Yes, realize that AWS generally does not work for that.

Start by researchng where your third party service is. Then find a data center close to it and then a reseller offering servers in this data center.

Simple good old "do your homework" does not fail you here.

Especially as any third party service where this matters is anyway a financial trading application of an exchange and thus far away from the usual main cloud providers. At least this is the only sensible scneario I can come up with where the milisecond counts. And no larger cloud provider is in a major financial center city.

Answer (score 0):

Determine where the third-party service is... e.g. if they're in New York, NY, then choose a provider/host/cloud service based in New York...